# How can I check for a stream before initializing one in a loop in C#

Tags: c#, html, c#-4.0, loops

I've got the following bit of code that generates a list I'm trying to process.  I need to create multiple files as I go through the list.

Currently I'm getting the following error on the calls to genStream outside of the IF, (in and out of the FOREACH loop), and I'm not sure why:

```
The name genStream' does not exist in the current context
```

I'm trying to figure out how I can close the one stream, and open another in the IF statement.  I tried to put a .close() before creating the new stream, and it gave me an error for using it before initializing the stream.

Here is my bit of code:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a file for each Genre, and writes movie info to each for the cooresponding movies
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cPath">Path to create HTML files in</param>
    /// <param name="mList">List of Movies to generate Genre and Movie info from</param>
    public static void WriteGenreHTML(string cPath, List<Movie> mList)
    {
        int lineID = 0;
        string tmpGen = null;
        string strHeader, strMovie, strGenre, tmpGenre = null;

        // Gets a list of unique Genres from the MovieList
        var distinctGenres = from m in mList
                             from genre in m.Genres
                             group genre by genre into genres
                             select genres.First();

        // Gets a list of Movies with the associated Genres
        var moviesWithGenre = from g in distinctGenres
                              from m in mList
                              where m.Genres.Contains(g)
                              orderby g, m.Title
                              select new { Genre = g, Movie = m };

        // Traverses list of movies creating new HTML Genre files, and writing movie info to the HTML genre files
        foreach (var m in moviesWithGenre)
        {
            // Creates new HTML file if new Genre is detected
            if (m.Genre != tmpGen)
            {
                tmpGen = m.Genre;

                // initiates streamwriter for catalog output file
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(cPath + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + m.Genre, FileMode.Create);
                StreamWriter genStream = new StreamWriter(fs);

                // Generates header info for new file, and new Genre
                strHeader = "<style type=\"text/css\">\r\n" + "<!--\r\n" + "tr#odd {\r\n" + "   background-color:#e2e2e2;\r\n" + "  vertical-align:top;\r\n" + "}\r\n" + "\r\n" + "tr#even {\r\n" + "   vertical-align:top;\r\n" + "}\r\n" + "div#title {\r\n" + "  font-size:16px;\r\n" + "    font-weight:bold;\r\n" + "}\r\n" + "\r\n" + "div#mpaa {\r\n" + "    font-size:10px;\r\n" + "}\r\n" + "\r\n" + "div#genre {\r\n" + " font-size:12px;\r\n" + "    font-style:italic;\r\n" + "}\r\n" + "\r\n" + "div#plot {\r\n" + "   height: 63px;\r\n" + "  font-size:12px;\r\n" + "    overflow:hidden;\r\n" + "}\r\n" + "\r\n" + "div#genre_heading {\r\n" + "    height: 50px;\r\n" + "  font-size: 24px;\r\n" + "   font-weight: bold;\r\n" + " text-align: center;\r\n" + "    text-decoration: underline;\r\n" + "}\r\n" + "-->\r\n" + "</style>\r\n" + "\r\n" + "<html>\r\n" + " <body>\r\n" + "     <table>\r\n";
                strHeader += "          <tr>\r\n" + "               <td colspan=2>\r\n" + "                 <div id=\"genre_heading\">" + m.Genre + "</div>\r\n" + "                </td>\r\n" + "          </tr>\r\n" + "\r\n";

                // Writes header HTML to stream
                genStream.WriteLine(strHeader);

                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Now Processing " + m.Genre);
            }

            // Generates the HTML for the Movie
            strMovie = lineID == 0 ? "          <tr id=\"odd\" style=\"page-break-inside:avoid\">\r\n" : "          <tr id=\"even\" style=\"page-break-inside:avoid\">\r\n";
            strMovie += "               <td>\r\n" + "                   <img src=\".\\images\\" + m.Movie.ImageFile + "\" width=\"75\" height=\"110\">\r\n" + "             </td>\r\n" + "              <td>\r\n" + "                   <div id=\"title\">" + m.Movie.Title + "</div>\r\n" + "                  <div id=\"mpaa\">" + m.Movie.Certification + " " + m.Movie.MPAA + "</div>\r\n" + "                  <div id=\"genre\">" + strGenre + "</div>\r\n" + "                   <div id=\"plot\">" + m.Movie.Plot + "</div>\r\n" + "                </td>\r\n" + "          </tr>\r\n";

            // Writes the HTML to the stream
            genStream.WriteLine(strMovie);
            lineID = lineID == 0 ? 1 : 0;
        }

        string closingHTML = "      </table>\r\n" + "   </body>\r\n" + "</html>";
        genStream.WriteLine(closingHTML);
        genStream.Close();
    }
```

Side note.  I'd GREATLY appreciate it if someone could point me towards something I can use to convert the HTML files into PDFs.  I tried EO, and it has a nasty "watermark", and chokes on files over a couple MB (mine are 5-10mb+).  I have WkHTMLToSharp, but I am not sure how to use it, and can't find any documentation on how to intitialize/use it.

Thanks as always!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the genStream outside of foreach loop, and then initialize it as needed within the if statement:

```
StreamWriter genStream;

foreach (var m in moviesWithGenre)
{
    // Creates new HTML file if new Genre is detected
    if (m.Genre != tmpGen)
    {
        tmpGen = m.Genre;

        // initiates streamwriter for catalog output file
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(cPath + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + m.Genre, FileMode.Create);
        // Set genStream to the FileStream
        genStream = new StreamWriter(fs);
```

Comment: Wow, that's a total DUH moment!  Thank you!

Comment: Any thoughts on the HTML->PDF, or WkHTMLToSharp?

Comment: The only library I've used for generating PDFs is ActivePDFToolkit, and that was to generate documents based on data from a third party via XML web services.  You might want to post a new question pertaining specifically to HTML->PDF or WkHTMLToSharp.

Comment: I added "genStream.Close();" under "tmpGen = m.Genre;" to ensure that I close the old stream before creating a new one.  However I'm getting "Use of unassigned local variable 'genStream'".  Also getting the same error on the "genStream.WriteLine(strMovie); that writes the HTML to the stream in the foreach loop (outside the IF)

Comment: I've posted a few questions about HTML->PDF and I received responses to try various websites, or expensive programs.  Two suggestions I got were EO, and the wkhtmltopdf.  I've posted a few questions on how to use the WkHTMLToSharp, and they have all gone completely unanswered :(

Comment: The initial error I posted is gone, but the answer, generates an error of "Use of unassigned variable 'genStream'".  It seems like I can only use the in the IF statement, or outside of the FOREACH loop.  I don't understand why.

Comment: @Dizzy - one solution might be to loop through each genre, and while in that genre generate the HTML page for the movies (with another loop).  It's not elegant, but it will get you moving forward.  Another option would be to keep a collection of FileStreams, but then you have to manage which one you're writing to, which would be even more painful.